# How to extend lease time while consuming from Spring Cloud Stream Reactor-based handlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, project-reactor

[Reactor-based handlers of `spring-cloud-stream`](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-reactive-programming-support) provide a neat interface to consume messages in a reactive manner:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public static class UppercaseTransformer {

    @StreamListener
    @Output(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public Flux<String> receive(@Input(Processor.INPUT) Flux<String> input) {
        return input.map(message -> message.toUpperCase());
    }

}
```

Though for certain type of consumed messages there might arise a need to extend the configured default lease time. How can one achieve that?

Comment: Perhaps you can elaborate a bit on _default lease time_. Aside from that please consider switching to [Spring Cloud Function programming model](https://spring.io/blog/2018/10/30/spring-cloud-stream-fishtown-rc1-2-1-0-rc1-release-announcement) within Spring Cloud Stream instead of using reactor module which will be deprecated in the next version given that most/all functionality it provides is already supported by Spring Cloud Function.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky, by *lease time* what I refer to is, for instance in the case of Google Pubsub, *acknowledgement deadline*. Further, I have checked the *Spring Cloud Function programming model* you mentioned, but AFAIU, it is definitely a no go for me since it requires blocking `Function<I, O>` calls, whereas my consumer is of type `Function<I, Mono<O>>`. Let me know if there is anything left unclear.

Comment: By `Function<I, Mono<O>>`, do you mean your input is a value (e.g., Message) yet the output is a `Mono`? or did you mean `Function<Flux<I>, Mono<O>>`? If the later then why do you say it won't work?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky, consider the following concrete example: given an input `Message`, my consumer returns `Mono<String>`. Here it doesn't matter if the input is of type `Message` or `Flux<Message>` -- each can be easily piped to the consumer via `flatMap`. Does this help?

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between `Function<I, Mono<O>>` and `Function<Flux<I>, Mono<O>>`. The first one is imperative and the later is declarative (reactive). The difference is, the first one is a typical listener added to the listening container of some type (e.g., Kafka, Rabbit etc). For the reactive the wiring with the container is different. In any event we do not support the later one - yet. But I am curious to hear more about your case, so consider raising an issue [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues), so we can continue. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies @OlegZhurakousky. Created [the ticket](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1589).